# React + Slack: webClient().oauth.v2 is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slack

I would like to get `channel information` with Slack authentication. Building it in React + Slack official library `@slack/web-api`. But **oauth_authorization_url_mismatch** error occurs...

1) Sign in with Slack
2) Redirect to callback url (http://localhost:3000/auth/slack/callback)
3) use `webClient()` failed

The error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): An API error occurred: oauth_authorization_url_mismatch
```

Slack oauth scope:
[image]
Add to Slack:

```
<a href={slackAuthorizeUrl}>
  <button className="btn btnSlack">
    <img
      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/slack.png`}
      alt="slack"
    />
    <span>Integrate with Slack</span>
  </button>
</a>
```

Setting:

```
REACT_APP_SLACK_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
REACT_APP_SLACK_OAUTH_SCOPE = 'channels:read,chat:write:bot'

export const slackAuthorizeUrl = `https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=${process.env.REACT_APP_SLACK_OAUTH_SCOPE}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_SLACK_CLIENT_ID}`;
```

Fetch info

```
import { WebClient } from "@slack/web-api";

let urlParamStr = window.location.search;

if (urlParamStr) {
  urlParamStr = urlParamStr.substring(1);
  let params = {};
  urlParamStr.split("&").forEach(param => {
    const temp = param.split("=");
    params = {
      ...params,
      [temp[0]]: temp[1]
    };
    const { code } = params;
    const result = new WebClient().oauth.v2.access({
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
      code
    });
    console.log("result", result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using v1 of the authorize URL `https://slack.com/oauth/authorize` but v2 of the access URL `new WebClient().oauth.v2.access`, which will cause this error.

Try using either `https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize` or `WebClient().oauth.access` to make both calls use the same api version.